# How to save python screen output to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to query items from a dict and save the printed output to a text file.

Here's what I have:

```
import json
import exec.fullog as e

inp = e.getdata() #inp now is a dict() which has items, keys and values.

#Query

print('Data collected on:', inp['header']['timestamp'].date())
print('\n CLASS 1 INFO\n')

for item in inp['Demographics']:
    if item['name'] in ['Carly', 'Jane']:
        print(item['name'], 'Height:', item['ht'], 'Age:', item['years'])

for item in inp['Activity']:
    if item['name'] in ['Cycle', 'Run', 'Swim']:
        print(item['name'], 'Athlete:', item['athl_name'], 'Age:', item['years'])
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110891/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-print-to-a-txt-file

Comment: Simply, continue printing whatever you want, to the cosole just like you do using `print` or `log` within the Python file; no specific change here. Now, while executing the python file `python3 yo.py`, simply replace the command with `python3 yo.py > logs.txt`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let me summarize all the answers and add some more.

- To write to a file from within your script, user [file I/O tools](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) that are provided by Python (this is the `f=open('file.txt', 'w')` stuff.
- If don't want to modify your program, you can use stream redirection (both on [windows](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) and on [Unix-like systems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/)). This is the `python myscript > output.txt` stuff.
- If you want to see the output **both** on your screen and in a log file, and if you are on Unix, and you don't want to modify your program,  you may use the [tee command](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/) ([windows version also exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)#Windows_PowerShell_2), but I have never used it)
- Even better way to send the desired output to screen, file, e-mail, twitter, whatever is to use the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). The learning curve here is the steepest among all the options, but in the long run it will pay for itself.

Answer (score 26):

`abarnert`'s answer is very good and pythonic. Another completely different route (not in python) is to let bash do this for you:

```
$ python myscript.py > myoutput.txt
```

This works in general to put all the output of a cli program (python, perl, php, java, binary, or whatever) into a file, see [How to save entire output of bash script to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554018/how-to-save-entire-output-of-bash-script-to-file) for more.

If you want the output to go to stdout *and* to the file, you can use tee:

```
$ python myscript.py | tee myoutput.txt
```

For more on tee, see: [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Comment: Actually, this is even more universally usable: simple `>` redirection works on Windows, and on almost all *nix shells, not just bash.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I'm blissfully unaware of Windows cmd, but I sit ~100ft from one of the creators of tcsh so I definitely should have known better. I've updated to reflect your info.

Comment: Well, cmd.exe is meant to be a superset of DOS command.com, which is a clone of the CP/M CCP with some minor changes, and I'll bet someone in your office at least has vague recollections of that. :)

Comment: this is really good but it does not print on terminal. Can we both print on txt and terminal?

Comment: @jachilles added!

Comment: Any way to append to the same file?

Comment: @hafiz031 Use `>>` (sh append operator) instead of `>` in the first example.

Answer (score 24):

A quick and dirty hack to do this **within the script** is to direct the screen output to a file:

```
import sys 

stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
```

and then reverting back to outputting to screen at the end of your code:

```
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```

This should work for a simple code, but for a complex code there are other more formal ways of doing it such as using [Python logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for isn't impossible, but it's probably not what you actually want.

Instead of trying to save the screen output to a file, just write the output to a file instead of to the screen.

Like this:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    print >>outfile, 'Data collected on:', input['header']['timestamp'].date()
```

Just add that `>>outfile` into all your print statements, and make sure everything is indented under that `with` statement.

---

More generally, it's better to use string formatting rather than magic `print` commas, which means you can use the `write` function instead. For example:

```
outfile.write('Data collected on: {}'.format(input['header']['timestamp'].date()))
```

But if `print` is already doing what you want as far as formatting goes, you can stick with it for now.

---

What if you've got some Python script someone else wrote (or, worse, a compiled C program that you don't have the source to) and can't make this change? Then the answer is to wrap it in another script that captures its output, with the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. Again, you probably don't want that, but if you do:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, './otherscript.py'])
with open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(output)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a really simple way in python 3+:

```py
f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
print('something', file = f)
```

^ found that from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110906/6794367

Answer (score 4):

You would probably want this. Simplest solution would be

Create file first.

open file via

```
f = open('<filename>', 'w')
```

or

```
f = open('<filename>', 'a')
```

in case you want to append to file

Now, write to the same file via

```
f.write(<text to be written>)
```

Close the file after you are done using it

```
#good pracitice
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple,  just make use of this example

```py
import sys
with open("test.txt", 'w') as sys.stdout:
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python script_name.py > saveit.txt
```

Because this scheme uses shell command lines to start Python programs, all the usual shell syntax applies. For instance, By this, we can route the printed output of a Python script to a file to save it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick way for this:

```py
log = open("log.txt", 'a')

def oprint(message):
    print(message)
    global log
    log.write(message)
    return()

code ...

log.close()
```

Whenever you want to print something just use oprint rather than print.

Note1: In case you want to put the function oprint in a module then import it,  use:

```py
import builtins

builtins.log = open("log.txt", 'a')
```

Note2: what you pass to oprint should be a one string (so if you were using a comma in your print to separate multiple strings, you may replace it with +)

Answer (score 0):

We can simply pass the output of python inbuilt print function to a file after opening the file with the append option by using just two lines of code:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as file:
    print('\nThis printed data will store in a file', file=file)
```

Hope this may resolve the issue...

Note: this code works with python3 however, python2 is not being supported currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
idx = 0
for wall in walls:
    np.savetxt("C:/Users/vimal/OneDrive/Desktop/documents-export-2021-06-11/wall/wall_"+str(idx)+".csv",
               wall, delimiter=",")
    idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, application_log_file, init_text="Program started", print_with_time=True):
        import sys
        self.__output_num = 0
        self.origin = sys.stdout
        self.init_text = init_text
        self.__init = False
        self.print_with_time = print_with_time
        self.log_file = application_log_file
        self.data = ""
        self.last_time = 0
        sys.stdout = self
        sys.stderr = self

    def flush(self):
        if self.data == "\n":
            return
        sys.stdout = self.origin
        print(self.__create_log_text(self.data) if self.print_with_time else self.data)
        with open(self.log_file, "a", encoding="utf-8") as log:
            log.write(self.__create_log_text(self.data))
        self.data = ""
        sys.stdout = self

    def __create_log_text(self, string: str):
        if self.last_time == str(datetime.datetime.today())[:-7]:
            return string
        self.last_time = str(datetime.datetime.today())[:-7]
        if not self.__init:
            self.__init = True
            return str(datetime.datetime.today())[:-7] + " | " + f"{self.init_text}\n"
        return str(datetime.datetime.today())[:-7] + " | " + string

    def write(self, data):
        self.data += data
```